# Entity Framework doesn't return result in Windows Service

Tags: entity-framework, windows-services

I have written a windows service which should query a database once a day and do something. the problem is that query has return data in my ASP.NET MVC project (I mean there is nothing wrong about the syntax of query), but it doesn't return any data in my Windows service project. Do have any idea why ef doesn't return data in windows service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple Windows service projects that all use EF without any issues at all.

There is very little difference between a Windows services and Console apps so my suggestion to you is to convert your windows service to a console application for easier debugging purposes.

Once this is operational then update your service.